# alias can't find a file that actually exists

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bashrc

On my personnal computer, not a server, in my `.bash_profile` (I'm on OSX) — sym-linked to `.bashrc`, I have the following line among some others :
`alias deploy=sh ~/dir/ectory/deploy.sh`

The file `deploy.sh` is chmoded `755`, and I can finely execute it manually. But everytime I launch my terminal, I got this message :

`-bash: alias: /Users/foo/dir/ectory/deploy.sh: not found`

This path exists, the file too. I have other aliases which work.

**Why is it throwing me this message?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that message because you didn't properly quote the space in your alias. Your alias should have the right side enclosed in quotes like this:

```
alias deploy='sh ~/dir/ectory/deploy.sh'
```